# Show that if $[m]_7 = [n]_7$, then $[3m]_7 = [3n]_7$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that if $[m]_7 = [n]_7$, then $[3m]_7 = [3n]_7$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

I remember that we had the property that $a\equiv b \pmod{7}$ *iff* $[a]_7 = [b]_7$. However, I couldn't find a way to use this here. If I have that $m\equiv n \pmod{7}$ then shouldn't I be able just to multiply the expression by $3$ to get  $3m\equiv 3n \pmod{7}$? I don't have any experience in proving residue classes so apologies if this is poorly expressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m\equiv n\pmod 7$ then this is equivalent to saying $m = n + 7k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $3m = 3n + 3\cdot 7k = 3n + 7\cdot (3k)$. Set $c = 3k$ then you have $3m = 3n + 7c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$, which implies that $3m\equiv 3n\pmod7$.

Also to be clear $[m]_7 = [n]_7$ is exactly the same as saying $m\equiv n\pmod7$, it's just different notation.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we have

$$\begin{align}
[a]_k=[b]_k&\iff a\equiv b\pmod{k}\\
&\iff k\mid a-b\\
&\implies k\mid \ell(a-b)\\
&\iff k\mid \ell a-\ell b\\
&\iff \ell a\equiv \ell b\pmod{k}\\
&\iff [\ell a]_k=[\ell b]_k.
\end{align}$$

Now just let $a=m, b=n, k=7, \ell=3$.

Comment: We have to precise that this is exact with $l$ not divisible by $k$ in third equivalence

Comment: That's why I used a one-way implication, @EDX.

Comment: Haven't see among equivelence sorry.

Comment: No worries, @EDX. There's value in pointing that part out nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

As, $p | a $ then it must be $p | ab $

So, Your conclusion "$[3m]_7 \equiv [3n]_7 $" is obvious , as $7 | (m-n) $.

Answer (score 0):

$$[m]_{7}=[n]_7 \iff 7|(m-n) \implies 7|3(m-n) \iff 7|(3m-3n) \iff [3m]_{7}=[3n]_7,$$
where the first and last equivalence are true by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Because 3 and 7 are co-prime, three as an inverse $\mod 7$

$$ [3]_7^{-1}=[5]_7$$

So by multiplying by this inverse in $F_7$ the relation $[3m]_7=[3n]_7$ we get :

$$ [m]_7=[n]_7$$

Answer (score 0):

$a \equiv b \pmod n$ then $ka \equiv kb \pmod n$ is one of the basic properties of modular arithmetic.

Proof:

$a\equiv b \pmod n$ means that $n|a-b$ or equivalently (and for some reason more intuitive to me) that $a = b + mn$ for some integer $m$. (These are equivalent statements because: $n|a-b\iff$ there is an integer $m$ so that $kn = a- b\iff$ there is an integer $m$ so that $a = mn + b$.)

So if $a\equiv b \pmod n$ then $a = b + mn$ for some integer $m$.  So $ka = kb + (km)n$ so $ka-kb=(km)n$ so $n|ka-kb$ so $ka \equiv kb \pmod n$.

That's all there is to it!

So if $[m]_7 = [n]_7$ then $m = n + 7k$ for some integer $k$ so $3m = 3n + 7(3k)$ so $[3m]_7=[3n]_7$.

........

!BUT! (there's always a but) it's important to realize that although you can multiply out you can't divide out.

It doesn't (always) follow that if $ka \equiv kb \pmod n\implies a \equiv b \pmod n$.

A counter example is $12 \equiv 6 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ so  $3*4 \equiv 3*2\equiv 3*0 \equiv 0 \pmod {6}$ but obviously $4\not \equiv 2 \not equiv 0\pmod {6}$.

... But it's not a *never* "but" it's only an "in general" but.

If $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime then you *can* divide.

So for example if $[3m]_7 = [3n]_7$ then $3m = 3n + 7k$ for some integer $7k$.  so $m = 3n + 7\frac k3$.  If $\frac k3$ is an integer then $[m]_7 = [n]_7$ but if $\frac k3$ is *not* an integer that is not so.

But $m$ is an integer and $n$ is an integer so $7\frac k3 = \frac {7k}3$ is an integer.  As $3$ and $7$ are relatively prime and have not factors in common $3$ must divide $k$ and $\frac k3$ must be an integer.

That *wont* work for $3*4\equiv 3*2 \pmod 6$ because $3$ and $6$ are *not* relatively prime.

$3*4 = 3*2 + 6k$ for some $k$.  So $4 = 2 + 6\frac k3$.  If $\frac k3$ is an integer then we would have $4 \equiv 2 \pmod 6$ but $\frac k3$ doesn't have to be an integer.  We could (and do) have $3$ and $6$ could share some factors in common.

(In this case $3*4 = 3*2 + 6(1)$ and $4=2 + 6\frac 13$.  $\frac 13$ is not an integer.)

Comment: Thanks! Great answer as always.